# Strange GWT behaviour in IE8

Tags: gwt, caching, internet-explorer-8

I experience a problem with GWT 1.6 in IE8 (I have enabled native XMLHTTP support).
The scenario i this: The first time I enter a page, it renders fine with no problems. But in subsequent requests, the page fails with a JavaScript error:

```
Message: Exception thrown and not caught
Line: 5067
Char: 237
Code: 0
URI: http://someurl/somehashcode.cache.html
```

It happens in both standard mode and compatibility mode. The strange thing is that I do not experience the error when I run the application on localhost through the ASP.NET dev server. Only when I run it from a Windows 2003 server.

Does anyone have an idea, why this happens?

I would appreciate any kind of help - thanks in advance.

/Henrik

Comment: I don't know about this problem. However, GWT 1.6 doesn't support IE8, for IE8 support you need at least GWT 1.7, but preferable GWT 2.0. My advice would be to first upgrade and than see if the problem still exists. See also other questions here related to what to take into account when upgrading.

Comment: You could do -PRETTY output of the GWT Javascript and see what line it's complaining about, but I'd say it's best to just upgrade to GWT 2.0. Besides 2.0 just being awesome, you can actually debug your GWT application in any browser and GWT will log your mystery exception more clearly than IE.

Answer (score 2):

You always use the last version of stable release of GWT. This kind of error is from GWT compiler and you must report it to GWT team. Maybe this problem fixed in the last version of GWT.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The team behind the GWT-driven component will soon update to 2.0. I hope it will solve the odd behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue, my feeling its coming from cached files. When the response is not from cached files I didn't  see an exception.

I'm doing SSL to IE8. Microsoft have a fix you could try:

Internet Explorer file downloads over SSL do not work with the cache control headers

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8

To resolve this issue in Internet Explorer 7 and in Internet Explorer 8, follow these steps: 
1.  Start Registry Editor.
2.  For a per-user setting, locate the following registry key: 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
For a per-computer setting, locate the following registry key: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
3.  On the Edit menu, click Add Value.
4.  To override the directive for HTTPS connections, add the following registry value: 
"BypassSSLNoCacheCheck"=Dword:00000001
To override the directive for HTTP connections, add the following registry value: 
"BypassHTTPNoCacheCheck"=Dword:00000001
5.  Quit Registry Editor.